# Express js sessions with rolling and polling

Tags: express, polling, express-session

I have used express-session module in mean.js app with rolling option enabled. I want to user logout after 15 min inactivity. Express session is resetting after internal calls goes to server like polling requests. How can i exclude some urls for rolling in express-session or is there any other approach like 2 different sessions for differnt urls .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up different sessions for different routes/routers:

```
let usersSession = session({
  name : 'myapp.users', // See below
  ...
});

let apiSession = session({
  name : 'myapp.api',
  ...
});

app.use('/users', usersSession, require('./users'));
app.use('/api', apiSession, require('./api'));
```

Be sure to set a different [name](https://github.com/expressjs/session#name) for each session(-cookie), otherwise they may interfere with each other.